# Why my code snippet in the condition still executing while the condition is not true?

Tags: javascript, html, input

```
          let Year = document.getElementById('year').value;
          let Month = document.getElementById('month').value;
          let date = document.getElementById("day").value;
         
          if(typeof Year !== "number" || typeof Month !== "number" || typeof date !== "number"){
            alert("Invalid Date ");
          }
```

I was expecting no alert as I input numeric values, but it was still displaying the alert message in the condition.

Comment: The `.value` property of any `<input>` is **always** a string.

Comment: Obviously the condition *is* true otherwise the alert statement would not be executed - computers don't make mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of Input is always string.

So, you can do like below.

```
let Year =document.getElementById('year').value;
let Month =document.getElementById('month').value;
let date =document.getElementById("day").value;
if(isNaN(Year+Month+date) ){
  alert("Invalid Date ");  
 
}
```

you need more validation like `date > 0` ... but my code is enough as your code now.

I think my answer can help you.

Comment: The problem here is that the `Year+Month+date` expression will be computed with the string values, meaning that the numeric strings will be *concatenated*, not added.

Comment: I know. `'2023' + '11' + '12' = '20231112'` . Do you think checking '20231112' is different from check 3 String each other? If `Month` is `"d"` for example, the sum is `2023d12` and the check result is also false.

Comment: Then you need to use `isNan(Number(...))` as this is more explicit

Comment: @Krokodil, try it yourself. `isNan("2")` is `false` and `isNan("d")` is `true`.

Comment: I think I write right answer but my answer is `-1` now. :(

Comment: Ok, perhaps, but that isn't the point. Please read my comment. It is extremely inexplicit and unreadable if you do it this way. And if, in the future, the project is migrated to a different language, then there is a high chance this would get translated incorrectly and the project will accumulate a logic error. This is because this is a JS feature, which makes it inexplicit in code. And there, I fixed your answer rating since that is so important

Comment: @J.Porter well that's true, I suppose. And I don't think for a reasonable time horizon we need to worry about numeric overflow :)